# Converting PHP String having a unix timestamp value to a MySQL Timestamp value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am setting a Database value within from a PHP file. In php file i have a string variable which stores unix timestamp value.

MySql table i am having is having a schema where i have to store these timestamp values in login field which is of timestamp datatype.

i tried sending

```
date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($userLogin));
```

to my database but all it stores is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: Have you confirmed the value of $userLogin is valid?  It's possible that strtodate() is returning FALSE (zero).  To debug, you should consider breaking the statement into two steps: 

1) assign the return value of strtotime() to a variable so you can validate it, and 
2) call date() using that newly created variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtotime () is intended for converting strings in various date formats into UNIX timestamps.  If the string is a timestamp already then it won't look like a meaningful formatted date/time to strtotime () and it will fail.

If the string is already a timestamp, then you don't need to do anything more to it than cast it to integer (strictly speaking even that step shouldn't be necessary, but casting will strip out any non-numerical characters, so it doesn't usually hurt to cast)

Additionally, MySQL is capable of parsing UNIX timestamps (with FROM_UNIXTIME(), I think, I'd have to look it up to be sure)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function for this.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL provides the `FROM_UNIXTIME( )` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP( )` functions to converta Unix timestamp to a MySQL date format, and vice versa.

Example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable(date, ..., ...) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME($yourdate), ..., ...)";
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$userLogin` holds `timestamp` value than you don't need to use `strtotime()`,

For example, this one should work -->

```
$userLogin = time();
date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $userLogin);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

```
    $login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',(int)($userLogin/1000));
```

and it worked...